# How do I submit my specific blogger category articles to Google News

Tags: blogger, sitemap, google-news

Is it possible on blogger platform to submit a specific category posts to Google News?

I searched and found that I need a specific [sitemap](https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/74288?hl=en) for Google News but since I am on blogger platform I am wondering if it can be done?

I saw some sites on `blogspot.com` appears in Google News but their sitemap seems to me normal when I access using `/sitemap.xml`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to retrieve a feed for a specific label. From the [Blogger Help Center](https://support.google.com/blogger/answer/97933?hl=en):

```
Atom 1.0: http://www.googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]
RSS 2.0:  http://www.googleblog.blogspot.com/feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?alt=rss
```

Unfortunately Google News requires specific tag definitions that can't be manipulated in the feed (Blogger side). The information for the required tags `<publication>`, `<publication_date>` and `<title>` is provided in the feed, but the markup is different. Giving that fact I would reccomend you to try to send the sitemap, you've got nothing to lose.

Take into account that it's possible to workaround the guideline "*Your News Sitemap should contain only URLs for your articles published in the last two days*" using the `max-results` param in the feed, where constant NUMBER is a mean/approximate/goal of the number of posts published in a timeframe of two days.

```
Atom 1.0: /feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?max-results=NUMBER
RSS 2.0:  /feeds/posts/default/-/[label]?alt=rss&max-results=NUMBER
```

Comment: Thank you. But but it does not follow the Google news xml https://support.google.com/news/publisher/answer/74288?hl=en

Comment: @Maria I understand. I've just edited my answer to provide some other details, I hope that help somehow.